# gradlew build not working in VSCode when I try to export my Minecraft mod

Tags: minecraft

So I finished my Minecraft mod and I tried to export it, so I typed ./gradlew build in Visual Studio's Terminal and it's not throwing errors or anything at me, it's just not working. Like, it literally doesn't do anything but go to the next line. I use a Mac, by the way

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if anyone has this same problem in VSCode, click the little elephant on the left side of the screen, then a bunch of folders will appear. Scroll through the folders until you find the folder named "build setup", open it. Next, find "wrapper" in the folder, hover your mouse over it, and then click the play button to make the wrapper. If you did this correctly, ./gradlew build(or .\gradlew build on Windows) should work!